# Any workaround on capturing case sensitive values using Xpath?

Tags: web-scraping, xpath

I have here say for example

```
<div aria-label="John Doe">
<div aria-label="john doe">
<div aria-label="jane doe">
```

I want to capture all of them using `doe`
I tried `.//div[contains(@aria-label, "doe")]` But this only works for the 2nd and 3rd line. For selector level 4 i think you may include the *identifier i* before the closing bracket (]) but I don't think I can use that here right? Is there any way around this?

Comment: looks like you are using a kind of scraping language, better add the relevant tags to your question

Comment: Sorry I don't know what tags to put. I hope it's good now.

Comment: what scrapper are you using?

Comment: Sorry could you briefly explain what scrappers are? Not familiar with the term :(

Comment: how you are using that selector? can you provide a complete code? .. the scraper is the tool/language you are using to get the data you want (unless I am missing the point of the question)

Comment: `.//div[contains(@aria-label, "doe")]` is XPath, not CSS Selector.

Comment: Title edited. So basically something like `page.click(.//div[contains(@aria-label, "doe")])` with a goal of capturing the three

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, you can use the case insensitive flag `i` on the attribute selector.

```css
[aria-label $= 'doe' i] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div aria-label="John Doe">A</div>
<div aria-label="john doe">B</div>
<div aria-label="jane doe">C</div>
```